# Unable to initialization of fastclick plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, click, fastclick.js

am having a problem in initializing fastclick plugin

1. am trying to initialize `fastclick plugin` with a `class` but it gives me error
   if am used this for a single `element` it works fine but if i want it to multiple `elements`it's through `error`

for a single `element` i used this method

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   var fastClickButton = document.querySelector('.parent');
   new FastClick(fastClickButton);
});
```

for multiple `element` having same `class`

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   var fastClickButton = document.querySelectorAll('.parent');
   new FastClick(fastClickButton);
});
```

in this method am unable to understand how can i fix this from my understand this plugin initialize from a `variable` and in this case this will select randomly only one element which has a `class`

i can't understand how can i achieve it

**2. the second problem is this**

this below code i have found on this plugin git page [url](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick)

```
$(function() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
});
```

but when i use this it through error that FastClick.attach is not a function

also am confused in this way

Please help me to fix this thanks

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a collection, you need to iterate over it as an array.

Comment: yup you right but how can i initialize it from a array @Barmar

Comment: i tried it but it not works it would be better if you show an example @Barmar

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with the plugin. But assuming your single element code works, I think this should work for multiple elements:

```
$(function() {
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.parent');
    for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        new FastClick(buttons[i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Fixed it. I mistakenly pasted QuerySelector instead of querySelectorAll.

Comment: yup its working now by `querySelectorAll` and other alternate is  `$('.parent')` thanks

Answer (score 0):

The recommended method of use is to instantiate FastClick on the `body` inside the load event handler:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    new FastClick(document.body);
}, false);
```